# SQL Assign "co-efficients" to query conditions and use them to sort result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I saw a query once that assigned some kind of ranking to query conditions, I can't remember it now.

They way I understood it, i think variable names (s1,s2,...)  were assigned to each of the conditions with a coefficient to give them different "weights" then the sum of the variables was used to sort the result.

It looked something like this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_name 
WHERE condition1='value1' as (s1*3) 
   OR condition2='value2' as (s2*2) 
   OR condition3='value3' as (s3*1) 
ORDER BY (s1+s2+s3)
```

So, the different numbers sort of give the conditions varying degrees of importance in the ORDER, makes it perfect for doing a related product/post search.

Please, does anyone know the right structure for this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you would define the aliases in the `SELECT` clause and then use them in the `ORDER BY`.  For instance:

```
SELECT t.*, (condition1 = 'value1') as s1, 
       (condition2 = 'value2') as s2,  (condition3 = 'value3') as s3
FROM table t
ORDER BY (s1*3 + s2*2 + s3*1);
```

Comment: what does the t.* mean?

Comment: @iKey . . . Is is a table alias, that is now defined.